# ASP.NET MVC template still missing from Monodevelop 2.2 Beta 2 on Windows?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, monodevelop

I have installed MonoDevelop 2.2 Beta 2 on Windows XP and seem to be missing the option which allows me to create an ASP.NET MVC project.

This was missing in MonoDevelop 2.1 Beta 1 but the release notes for Beta 2 state that it was included in the installer for Beta 2.

Any thoughts on why I still can't see it? Have I missed a step or is the bug still there? Anyone else tried this?

Note: I also have Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 installed on this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also didn't find it in 2.2 beta 2, but it's fortunately present in MonoDevelop 2.2 release.

Comment: Yes, please upgrade to Monodevelop 2.2 final release, as this has been around since December.

Comment: Co-incidentally I just installed the final release this morning shortly before you both commented on this and - as you say - it is now there. Thanks for your replies.